# Add Docker registry certificate to Docker application on my Mac

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a Docker secure registry setup and I would like to push/pull images from my Mac. I have installed Docker Quickstart Terminal in Mac and the only way I could authenticate to the registry is

```
1. Do a docker-machine ssh default
2. Drop the CRT file in /etc/docker/certs.d/abc-registry.com/ca.crt
3. sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

If I do not do the aforementioned steps on every boot, I get the following error:

```
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://abc-registry.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://abc-registry.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is there a way to permanently add the certs to docker ? Or stop docker app from regenerating certs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this from https://github.com/SvenDowideit/boot2docker/blob/4942238743be6a4c6cb930353c7f09dc01006cfa/README.md

> From Boot2Docker version 1.6.0, you can add your Registry server's
>   public certificate (in .pem format) into the
>   /var/lib/boot2docker/certs/ directory, and Boot2Docker will
>   automatically load it from the persistence partition at boot.

Comment: But this is applicable for boot2docker but no for docker terminal mac app right ?

Comment: Boot2docker is actually the operating system image used for the `docker terminal mac app` , so yes it should work.